# Difference and relation between firmware and device driver

Tags: drivers, firmware

1. How are firmware and device driver
   different and related? I think both
   control devices?
2. Is firmware always self-booting,
   while driver must be run/booted by OS?

Answer (score 31):

1. Firmware is the software that runs *on* the device.  A driver is the software that tells your operating system how to communicate with the device.  Not all devices have firmware--only devices with some level of intelligence.
2. I'm not exactly sure what you mean... generally speaking, firmware has nothing to do with "booting"... I think maybe what you're asking is, do devices with firmware always have the firmware installed on the device, or is it loaded after boot time.  If that's what you're asking, the answer is no...

Most commonly, devices with firmware have the firmware programmed into the device (either with a ROM chip, or a programmable ROM chip), but there are some devices where the firmware is loaded into the device at initialization time.  I can think of some network cards and webcams that operate this way, but I'm sure there are others as well.

Comment: Thanks! in 2, by self-booting, I mean that if the firmware is run by itself not by others, while driver is run by OS not by itself? I picked up the word self-booting from "Without an operating system, a user cannot run an application program on their computer, unless the application program is self booting" in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system

Comment: Firmware is run by the hardware device itself... I think that answers the question? Consider this: Many non-computer devices have "firmware"--such as digital cameras, DVD players, cell phones, etc. So obviously in these cases, the firmware is completely self-contained in the device itself. Only if/when you plug one of those devices into your computer do you need a _driver_.

Comment: Thanks! From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_software: "Firmware is low-level software often stored on electrically programmable memory devices. Firmware is given its name because it is treated like hardware and run ("executed") by other software programs." Is firmware run by other software programs or by the hardware itself?

Comment: @Celeritas: Because only devices with some level of intelligence have firmware, in contrast to those (like an RS-232 port) which do not. If you're comparing devices that have an entire OS (mobile phone, iPod, programmable GPS, etc), you're talking about a completely different abstraction layer, which really has nothing to do with "device drivers" in the traditional sense. This class of access software is often called a "device driver", but in reality it's a network application protocol implemented on top of a device driver (such as that which communicates with a USB port or bluetooth).

Comment: It's a little weird reading this answer a decade later. "only devices with some level of intelligence." -- that describes practically everything these days.

Answer (score 13):

[Firmware](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firmware) implements low-level details that are required to operate the hardware, and provides an API/ABI to a higher level. A device driver provides an adapter between the OS and the API/ABI exposed by the firmware.

Comment: Thanks! Is device driver part of the OS, and run by the OS kernel? Is firmware part of the device, and run by which, the OS kernel or the firmware itself?

Comment: The device driver is considered part of the OS, and usually runs on the host CPU. Firmware is *usually* run by the device; it may be uploaded to the device by the OS though.

Answer (score 8):

The modern definition or common usage of *firmware* has nothing to do with a specific software functionality.  Firmware is simply software that is stored in non-volatile semiconductor memory (e.g. PROM, EEPROM or flash) chips rather than a mass storage device such as a hard drive.  The stored software could be a monolithic linked binary, or consist of loader, kernel and application modules.  (OTOH I've seen some TV tuner cards for PCs that require loading of "firmware" by the Linux kernel in order to complete initialization.)

The origin of the term has to do with processor-controlled logic versus hardwired logic. Software stored on hard drives could be easily modified and updated.  Revisions and updates to hardwired logic required board or module redesign and replacement.  The middle ground was a processor executing software to control hardware. The software was called **firm**ware to reflect the middle ground between **soft**ware versus **hard**wired logic.  Originally the firmware was stored in ROM, PROM or EPROM chips in order to maintain board modularity.  The advancement of EEPROM and flash chips allowed in-circuit and on-board updates of the firmware.

As processors (and peripherals) got smaller and cheaper and less power hungry, the possibilities for embedding them in every kind of device/appliance expanded.  In order to make the software to operate these devices rugged and secure, the software is stored in flash memory chips rather than a hard drive; it also makes the device smaller and a lot cheaper.  The term firmware has been expanded to encompass all software in devices/appliances with embedded processors, even though some parts of the stored code could have no relationship to replacing hardwired logic.

Comment: Then what does it mean to install firmware on massive storage?  Like this [Debian package](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/firmware-linux-nonfree)?

Comment: @xuhdev - That Debian package consists of files that can be used by various Linux device drivers. The files are refereed to as *"firmware"* since they are are written to the attached device by the Linux driver.  The files may contain operational data or code for the embedded uC/uP of the device.  Note that this file transferred to the device is loaded into the device's volatile memory, and loading has to occur after every device or system reset.  The *"installation"* of this *"firmware"* on the host's mass storage is merely a procedural mechanism (i.e. package handling).

Comment: I like the etymological explanation for the vernacular term,  the nomenclatural convention makes a lot more sense now!

Answer (score 6):

[Someone posted this question recently](https://superuser.com/questions/879908/what-is-the-difference-between-bios-and-firmware), saying:

> Firmware is a combination of persistent memory, program code, and the
>   data stored in it. Typical examples of devices containing Firmware are
>   embedded systems such as traffic lights, consumer appliances, digital
>   watches, computers, computer peripherals, mobile phones, and digital
>   cameras. The Firmware contained in these devices provides the control
>   program for the device.

In fact, SuperUser's `drivers` tag is defined:

> A driver, also called a device driver or software driver is software
>   that allows higher-level computer programs to interact with a hardware
>   device. When a computer program requests interaction with a certain
>   hardware device, the driver will handle instruction and output
>   translation between the device and the computer program invoking the
>   driver.

and, the `firmware` tag is defined:

> In general, the difference between software and firmware is the level
>   at which it interacts with the hardware. Firmware interacts at the
>   very low level of the hardware while software interacts at high
>   levels. Firmware generally controls the basic timing, controls and
>   functionality of hardware.

Originally I thought that `firmware` was installed onto the chip or board directly and lived there, which is why it has to be "flashed", whilst you would install a `driver` on top of an operating system.

Conclusion:

`Firmware` allows the hardware to "do" stuff, and `drivers` allow software to interact with the hardware.

Answer (score 2):

For **computer platforms**, microcontroller firmware implements some functionalities of hardware and
provides some interfaces. UEFI firmware works with microcontroller firmware to handle the computer
before OSs and its drivers kick in, initializes the hardware and provides necessary information to
the OSs. Thus, the OSs can install the correct drivers and drivers know the available way to control
the hardware.  Drivers can invoke firmware routines or directly control the hardware to carry out
tasks send by OSs. All firmware is **self-contained subsystems** automatically load and run when
hardware switchs on
, can work together to compose a bigger system. OS drivers provide interfaces for
hardware/software, is part of a OS, have to loaded by OSs, can't directly run by hardware.

**Firmware** is a software system developed for a specific hardware platform. Its role vary
significantly for different hardware platform. Let's see some examples.

On mainboards, there are one or more PCIe controllers. A PCIe controller is typically implemented as
a microcontroller. **A microcontroller** is a small integrated circuit (IC) that contains a CPU core,
memory, and various peripherals, all integrated into a single chip. These microcontrollers are
designed to handle specific tasks and functions efficiently. In the case of a PCIe controller, the
microcontroller is specifically tailored to manage the data transfer and communication between the
Central Processing Unit (CPU) and the PCIe devices connected to the mainboard. The software system
runs on these microcontrollers is firmware.  Microcontroller firmware is invoked to initialize and
control PCIe devices. There is a similar microcontroller and firmware with similar roles in almost
all mainboard components (Network Interface Card (NIC) , Hard Drive (HDD/SSD) Controller)and
peripheral devices (USB flash memory, printer).

**Unified Extensible Firmware Interface (UEFI)** is a specification prescribing the architecture of the
firmware used by computer platforms. The CPU on a computer is hardwired to run the UEFI firmware.
The UEFI firmware initializes the hardware components and loads its modules stage by stage which is
called **UEFI boot stages**.  Security Phase (SEC) is the first stage. It configures temporary RAM
(often CPU cache as RAM), configures stack and heap in the temporary RAM, invokes Pre-EFI
Initialization (PEI) with location and size of firmware volume (FV), temporary RAM, stack and heap.
Main memory is not available yet. PEI is the second stage. It does the main memory and other early
hardware initialization, also does firmware recovery operations. The third stage is Driver Execution
Environment (DXE). As main memory available now, most modules are loaded and most hardware is
initialized, like CPU, chipset, mainboard, and boot devices. EFI drivers or Option ROMs of PCI
devices are executed. The fourth stage is Transient System Load (TSL). Here you either enter the
UEFI shell or execute an UEFI application, like the Operating System (OS) boot loader. Then, the
last stage Runtime (RT) comes. The loaded OS takes over the computer.

As you can see, UEFI firmware and microcontroller firmware is quite different. UEFI firmware looks
like an OS, has drivers, applications and graphic user interface (GUI)/command-line interface(CLI).
It invokes microcontroller firmware to control other devices. Contrast to that, microcontroller
firmware is way simpler, without GUI/CLI, only responsible for one component or peripheral device.

The software systems used by video game consoles (PlayStation, Xbox), routers, switches, kiosks, and
many embeded systems used in vehicles, appliances, robots and Internet of Things (IoT) devices are
frimware too. Like the UEFI firmware, some of them have similar features with an OS, like user
applications, system applications, kernel, drivers, boot loaders. It is not very clear in some cases
if it is an OS or firmware. But they are all **designed for a specific hardware platform with
relatively specific purposes**. While OSs are more general, run on a variety of hardware platforms
and can do all the things the above devices do.

**A driver** is a software system developed to provide interfaces of hardware/software which are invoked
by other software systems.  It can has a layered architecture.  **Driver stack** refer to a hierarchical
arrangement of multiple drivers that work together to enable the communication between a hardware
device and the OS or software applications. Each layer in the driver stack is responsible for
specific tasks, and the interaction between the layers allows for efficient handling of hardware
functionality and data flow. Layered drivers are common in modern operating systems to provide
modularity, flexibility, and support for a wide range of hardware devices. It is obviouly that
drivers have to correctly communicate with the hardware/software which it provides interfaces, and
the software which invokes the interfaces.