# Can Linux boot on ARM without firmware?

Tags: linux, boot, firmware, arm

I am using bootwrapper aarch64 and Linux on a ARM verstaile express board and not able to understand who plays the role of Firmware ? I have seen on another varients where UEFI and ARM trusted firmware are used along with Linux ...why similiar things are not required on Bootwrapper + Linux combination?

Can experts please help me understand that?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: The problem with your question is the definition of *"firmware"*, which has evolved from its original meaning.  See https://superuser.com/questions/299442/difference-and-relation-between-firmware-and-device-driver/299517#299517

Comment: Okay...so i exactly meant to understand that what role ARm trusted firmware does ..who plays the same role with Boot wrapeer varient ?